# Unity: Extend Source Code Using Partial Classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I have noticed that most of their classes are marked `partial`. I know that the partial keyword is used to split a `class` definition across multiple source files. Therefore, would it be safe to "extend" Unity classes using the `partial` keyword, given that I only add methods and properties? (I mean C# properties, a.k.a. getter-setters).

E.g.

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    public partial class Transform
    {
        public float PositionX {
            get => position.x;
            set => position = new (
                x: value,
                y: position.y,
                z: position.z
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you haven't tried it yet, because what you thought is [impossible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#restrictions). Unless you happen to be able to access and compile Unity's source code.

> All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

To extend Unity classes, you need to use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5811 for imformation on the status of the addition of extension properties to a future version of C#.